# Can't opt out of Beta downloads

Tags: mac-appstore, beta-seed-program

I opted out of beta downloads under System Preferences > App Store, but I still see macOS beta downloads in the Mac App Store.

How can I fix this? Caching issue?

Answer (score 1):

From:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/30929430#30929430

Once you've unenrolled, run this command in the terminal:

```
sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
```

This worked for me!

Comment: 31415927:~ williamcerniuk$ sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
Password:
Catalog management is no longer supported.
31415927:~ williamcerniuk$

Answer (score 0):

Once you unenroll in System Preferences, beta updates will still appear until the next commercial release of the software that you opted-in for (macOS or iOS). At that time, you can upgrade to the stable commercial release and you will no longer receive beta notifications.

If you further wish to leave the beta program entirely, after unenrolling in System Preferences go to the [Apple Beta unenroll](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll) page and click the link at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: I have the same issue as OP. I Opted out on system preferences & unenrolled on Apple Beta website. However even with Sierra Alpha, App Store still reminds me for the beta update and actually tries to restart itself to update resulting in a kernel panic/shutdown. Reinstalled OS twice and reset NVRAM/PRAM yet the issue remains.

Comment: I hope this holds true in macOS 11. It keeps on pestering me to update to macOS 11.1 beta. And while the only difference between "release" and "beta" these days is the calendar date, I still would rather wait until it is more than half baked.